# Google Maps Help - placing city name above markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps v3.

I have a lot of markers on my map, so many that it covers the city name from being visible on the underlining map.

Is it possible, and how, to have the city name displayed above the markers?

For example, currently, the layers look like this.

```
Layer 1 - Map Markers (on top of map)
Layer 0 - Google Map (with city names rendered on map)
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
Layer 2 - City name
Layer 1 - Map Markers
Layer 0 - Google Map (without city names displayed)
```

Answer (score 3):

The city names are rendered on the map imagery, so at the moment it is not possible to separate the two layers.

However, you may want to consider:

- Using different marker sizes for different zoom levels (using smaller markers when zoomed-out).
- Reducing the opacity of your markers.
- Adding your own layer of city names. You can use the new [Styled Maps feature](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps) in the v3 API to remove the city names from the imagery. You can try this out using the [Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), turning off all administrative labels.